# Change td content to select and vice versa

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a `tr` and if you click on it it will change to `select` and enable the user to select an option. How can I make it go back to `td` with the new value after the user clicks away from the input?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".departamento").one('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var currentEle = $(this);
    var value = $(this).html();
    select = '<select class="form-control" id="departamento" name="departamento">' +
      '<option name="Comercial" <?php echo ($departamento == "Comercial")?"selected":""; ?> >Comercial</option>' +
      '<option value="Suporte Tecnico" <?php echo ($departamento == "Suporte Tecnico")?"selected":""; ?> >Suporte Técnico</option>' +
      '<option value="Direcao" <?php echo ($departamento == "Direcao")?"selected":""; ?> >Direção</option>' +
      '<option value="Formacao "<?php echo ($departamento == "Formacao")?"selected":""; ?> >Formação</option>' +
      '</select>';
    currentEle.html(select);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Departamento</th>
    <td class="departamento">
      <?php echo $departamento;?>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Comment: use event delegation on your event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can switch the content of the `td` back on the `blur` event of the `select`. You can also tidy the logic up to use a class to allow the switch of content so that you don't need to use `one()`, which will only allow the operation to happen once.

Also note that you can improve the logic which selects the default value in the select by doing it based on the text of the `td`, instead of having to put a lot of spaghetti PHP in to the JS. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".departamento").on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var $td = $(this);

    if ($td.hasClass('active'))
      return;

    var value = $td.text().trim();
    $td.empty();
    var $select = $('<select class="form-control" id="departamento" name="departamento">' +
      '<option name="Comercial">Comercial</option>' +
      '<option value="Suporte Tecnico">Suporte Técnico</option>' +
      '<option value="Direcao">Direção</option>' +
      '<option value="Formacao">Formação</option>' +
      '</select>').val(value).appendTo($td).focus();
      $td.addClass('active');
  }).on('blur', 'select', function() {
    var $select = $(this);
    var $td = $select.closest('td');
    $td.html($select.val()).removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Departamento</th>
    <td class="departamento">
      Direcao
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
$(document.body).on('change', 'select' ,function(){
   $('.departamento').text(this.value );
 });
```

Add a click handler on select and change html of div with class 'departamento'.

Comment: i doubt this will work since select is added dynamically

Comment: Updated: Attach event to a document element which is always present like body to find the dynamically generated item.